# How to use external configuration file properties with a common one included in Spring Boot 2

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

In my Spring Boot 2 Application, I want to load a specific properties file (by profile) **located in an external path**, but I want that they load the common application.properties file in the project:

My config folder:

`D:/config
         | -> hello-dev.properties (server.port=7777)
         | -> hello-prod.properties (server.port=5555)`

And in my local application.properties:

`logging.file=firstLog.log`

So my aim, is to launch my spring boot application with `dev`profile and the 2 properties will be loaded (`server.port=7777` and `logging.file=firstLog.log`)

I am also conscient that my external property configuration files are prefixed by `hello` instead of default one `application.properties`

Thank you for your help

Comment: Add `-Dspring.config.name=application,hello` and `-Dspring.config.addition-location=file:/D:/config/` which should do what you want.

Comment: I executed this command but didn't work, it loads the default port 8080:
`spring-boot:run -Dspring.profiles.active=dev -Dspring.config.name=application,hello -Dspring.config.addition-location=file:/D:/Config`

Comment: You need to pass that as arguments so instead of `-D` use `--` instead.

Comment: It worked!!! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
java -jar myproject.jar --spring.config.additional-location=classpath:/default.properties,classpath:/override.properties
```

Look at the chapter about externalized configuration: 
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

Comment: Don't use `spring.config.location` if you want to add location use the new `spring.config.additional-location` for that.